# Add folder to RSpec::Rails::RequestExampleGroup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails

I have a `spec/admin/controllers` folder and I want to add all controllers inside that folder to `RSpec::Rails::RequestExampleGroup`. How to add it? I know I can manually add `type: :controller` to every controllers. But I wanna more DRY approach :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood what you were asking, and considering all the specs in question are contained in a specific location, you could do something like this:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include RSpec::Rails::RequestExampleGroup, example_group: {
    file_path: /spec\/admin\/controllers/
  }
end
```

(Or incorporate the conde inside the `do...end` in a preexisting `RSpec.configure` block)